# MySQL optimize/ alternative to LIKE for short fields (username/email)

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and in the backoffice of my application I permit the administrator to search for users by typing part of their name.

The naive query is

```
SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE '%something%'
```

I do know that in the generic case, you would prefer a FULLTEXT index to replace `LIKE` however I don't think it applies as we're doing search for inside one word, while FULLTEXT shine when you search words in a document

I also know that if i was only doing `something%` , a simple index works great to.

Is there a "state of the art" solution to make an efficient `contains` operation ? Or is `LIKE '%something%` is already the best we can do in that use case ?

Comment: I suspect there will be a cost either way - but how about an option for 'username starts with:' to allow for an indexed search?

Comment: unfortunately it was proposed but rejected, it's hard to convince people that having a slow search is also "bad ux"